# overloaded method value filter with alternatives: in play-framework 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I upgraded to play 2.6 from play 2.4 i am getting this compile time error

```
[error] myproject/app/models/jsonparsing/DirectUserSignUpJsonValidation.scala:27: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
[error]   (error: play.api.libs.json.JsonValidationError)(f: String => Boolean)play.api.libs.json.Reads[String] <and>
[error]   (f: String => Boolean)play.api.libs.json.Reads[String]
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.data.validation.ValidationError)
[error]       filter(ValidationError("Password length is less than 8"))(_.length >= 8).
```

here is the code

```
case class DirectUserSignUpValidation(firstName: String,
                                      lastName: String,
                                      email: String,
                                      password: String) extends Serializable

object DirectUserSignUpValidation {
  var validationErrorMsg=""
  implicit val readDirectUser: Reads[DirectUserSignUpValidation] = (
  (JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "lastName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
    (JsPath \ "password").read[String].
      filter(ValidationError("Password length is less than 8"))(_.length >= 8).  
      filterNot(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))(_.forall(_.isDigit)).
      filterNot(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))(_.forall(_.isLetter))
    )(DirectUserSignUpValidation.apply _)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new play-json libs now work with `JsonValidationError` and you are using the old `ValidationError`.